# Integrate grails with hashicorp vault

Tags: grails, hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to integrate hashicorp vault on a grails app. I wasn't able to find a tutorial or some help on the internet. Even the grails documentation doesn't comment anything on this topic.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

I'm using grails 2.5.6

**Edit**

By integration I mean to let grails read properties from hashicorp vault instead of the ones that I defined in Config.groovy or DataSource.groovy or another properties in classpath. I defined a custom place holder that is able to reach my hashicorp vault but grails is not recognizing the properties I brought.

MyPlaceholderConfigurer.java

```
public class MyPlaceholderConfigurer extends GrailsPlaceholderConfigurer { 
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyPlaceholderConfigurer.class); 

    public MyPlaceholderConfigurer(GrailsApplication application) { 
        super(application); 
        logger.info("XXXXXXXXX: Started MyPlaceholderConfigurer"); 
    } 

    @Override 
    protected void loadProperties(Properties props) throws IOException { 
        logger.info("XXXXXXXXX: loadProperties()"); 
        super.loadProperties(props); 
        Map<String, Object> vault = HashicorpVault.getSecrets(); 
        props.putAll(vault); 
    } 
}
```

resources.groovy

```
propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer(MyPlaceholderConfigurer, application) { 
    environment = getUnrefreshedApplicationContext().getEnvironment() 
}
```

Config.groovy

```
grails.config.locations = ["classpath:Principal.properties", "classpath:MyDatabase.groovy"]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no client library for groovy (or grails-plugin).

Since groovy works good with java you can just use the `java-client` library (https://www.vaultproject.io/api/libraries.html) the one you most likely want is  https://github.com/BetterCloud/vault-java-driver since the Spring version of the driver can conflict with grails' Spring version. Also, the non-spring version targets java 7+ so you won't end up solving `java 8 new features` -problems that are not supported in old groovy versions bundled with grails 2.5.x

Modify your `BuildConfig.groovy` to get the library:

```
dependencies {

    ...

    compile 'com.bettercloud:vault-java-driver:3.1.0'

    ...
}
```

And follow the instructions on github page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated my question. Basically I'm able to reach hashicorp vault but I'm not able to let grails use the properties I brought. Do you know how grails can use the properties I brought instead of the one defined on DataSource.groovy, etc. ?

Comment: In Config.groovy for example you can just say `some.setting = SomeCustomConfigObject.get("myPassword")` for example and then create `SomeCustomConfigObject` with static method `get(String key)` and make it do whatever you want to return the value for `myPassword`. This is read when the app starts. Maybe make a wrapper for the vault for this purpose? What you are doing is not wrong, but there is something you are missing to make it work and I can't easily help you with that, sorry.